# NodeJS http-server - How can I log the client IP to the console?

Tags: node.js, windows, swagger-ui, httpserver

Running "http-server --cors" at a Windows command prompt from my swagger-ui-dist directory displays lines of connection events as they occur. How do I add the calling client IP to the displayed line?

Comment: @NickRamsbottom Unless I am mistaken, the poster is asking specifically about the [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) module, not the node native `http` module.

Comment: @zero298, my bad. I wasn't 100% so didn't post as an answer. Comment removed!